# Photobooth video

Tags: video, macos

When recording a video with the photobooth app how can the video be reversed or mirrored? Cause when I show items in the video all the writing in the labels are reversed

Answer (score 1):

I have often wondered the same when looking at mirrored text in images captured...   I think you could use a video editor to flip the frame horizontally and then output the render to a new file which views correctly. It should be easier. The software should just be smart enough to do it. Other low tech option; video a mirror that has you in it. Then, you record (and flip), a flipped image. I'd do it in After Effects easily. You might do it in a lower priced editing app like VLC on a mac, however. I have not tested that though. QuickTime might even do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an iSight camera to confirm this works, but there are menu items for 'Flip photo' & 'Auto flip new items'

[image]